# Drupal 7- How to make a custom module for only front page?

Tags: drupal, themes

so..I created page--front.tpl.php in my theme directory and it works fine.

now, how do I make a variable that can be used in the page--front.tpl.php?

I can write my php codes inside page--front.tpl.php, but I think there is a better way.

added:

on the front page, I am going to query video and news nodes ONLY. That is why I want to make a new module for only front page.

any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to pass some data to the template and display them from different template from the other pages?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but OK. You have two options: one is what you're doing now. Write your custom PHP in `page--front.tpl.php` and you'll be fine. The other is ditching the file and working only with `page.tpl.php`.

The variable `$is_front` tells you whether you're on the front page. You can write custom PHP in a conditional block: `if ($is_front) { ... }`.

Also, you can create a custom block (a view, perhaps, depending on your needs) and set its display restrictions to "only on the listed pages" - and list  there. You'll have a custom view loaded only on the front page.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do have a custom front page is configure your front page in the site information settins (admin/settings/site-information in D6).

Creating a module to display that content is then a completely different thing.

What I would *really* suggest is looking at [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) if you don't know it already. That allows you to build lists of things (nodes, users, ...) and expose them as pages, blocks, rss feeds and much more. You can create a list of nodes with types video and news, expose that as a page and then just point your front page to the path of your view.

Answer (score 0):

you might try using the views module to create your list of videos and nodes. You can set a views page to be your homepage in the site settings.